# How to create a database for two java classes inheriting from an abstract class

Tags: java, database

I was asked how would a database look like (basically how many tables) if we have an abstract class Animal and Two classes  Horse and Donkey both inheriting from Animal. Do i need three tables or just two? what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

One could keep it very simple:

```
Table: animal (id, name, etc.)
```

ex.

```
animal (1, horse, etc.)
```

When you need multiple tables, would be when you have multiple attributes

```
Table: animal (id, name, movement_type, diet_type)

Table: movement_type (id, type)

Table: diet_type (id, type)
```

ex.

```
movement_type (1, Quadruped)
movement_type (2, Biped)

diet_type (1, Herbivore)
diet_type (2, Omnivore)

animal (1, Horse, 1, 1)
animal (2, Human, 2, 2)
```

It is good to build tables for data that it repetitive. Your data stays far more accurate with this type of structure.

Furthermore, to take a step into OOP, you would need one class for a donkey and a horse, with two separate instantiation of the class.

ex.

```
Animal horse = new Equidae("Seabiscuit", "tranquil", "sport");
Animal donkey = new Equidae("Fred", "ambitious", "work");
```

A different class is necessary iff two objects will have different behaviors. A donkey and horse are part of the family Equidae, and their behaviors are the same. The properties that make them up are different, but behaviors are the same.

*The flip side to this, is that the most important thing is that your program works and your database stores data. These are common practices, but "there are a million ways to skin a goldfish".*

I hope this helps in answering your question.

Comment: so you are saying if we had an abstract class animal and two classes dog and fish extending from Animal, we could havein our database eg table animal and table habitat (terrestrial/aquatic) ? not necessarily having table dog and table fish